# Get index of a list with tuples in which the first element of the tuple matches pattern

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing, tuples, valueerror

I have a list of tuples:

```
    countries = [('Netherlands','31'),
                 ('US','1'),
                 ('Brazil','55'),
                 ('Russia','7')]
```

Now, I want to find the index of the list, based on the first item in the tuple.

I have tried `countries.index('Brazil')`, I would like the output to be `2`. But instead, that returns a ValueError:

`ValueError: 'Brazil' is not in list`

I am aware that I could convert this list into a pd DataFrame and then search for a pattern match within the first column. However, I suspect there is a faster way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `enumerate()` to find your index:

Try:

```py
idx = next(i for i, (v, *_) in enumerate(countries) if v == "Brazil")
print(idx)
```

Prints:

```
2
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems like this code returns the index of the first index, which suffices for my problem. Just based on my own curiosity: do you know of an alternative that would return multiple indices, whenever it applies?

Comment: @Emil You can use list-comprehension, e.g.: `indices = [i for i, (v, *_) in enumerate(countries) if v == "Brazil"]`